# C++ objects and memory allocation

Tags: c++, object, memory

Assume I have the following code:

```
Object* obj = new Object();
void* mem = malloc(sizeof(obj) + 40);
*((Object*)mem) = *obj;
```

In that case, is it guaranteed that `obj` data would be stored at the beginning of the `malloc`ed memory, and can I use the rest of the block `mem + sizeof(obj)` without overriding `obj`?

Comment: Undefined behaviour is guaranteed.

Comment: ok, let's ask the question --what is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: This won't work, because the assignment operator in the third line expects that the `Object` you are assigning to is a valid Object (i.e. one that was already constructed and in a valid state), but you are using a pointer (`mem`) to a bunch of uninitialized bytes instead.  You might have better luck using placement-new, e.g. `Object * newObj = new (mem) Object();`

Comment: We were asked to implement malloc and free functions. In order to implement free I need the details about the memory allocated, so my idea was to allocate extra space, so under the user's memory block, I will save a object containing the details about the allocation (size, etc...).

Comment: What is the right way to it then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're guaranteed to have an undefined behaviour.

First, `sizeof(obj)` is size of a pointer, not size of `Object`. Use `sizeof(*obj)` or `sizeof(Object)`. Second, there is no `Object` at the location `mem`, so this dereference `*((Object*)mem)` is undefined behaviour.

Use [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new):

```
new (mem) Object(*obj); // or new (mem) Object(std::move(*obj));
```

to put `Object` at the beginning of `mem` block. You can use `40` remaining bytes at your own discretion.

Comment: Better yet, he could use `sizeof(Object)` and thereby eliminate the `Object* obj = new Object();` line entirely.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, it might be the case that `obj` it somehow modified after first `new`. If it is not the case, I agree with your comment.

Comment: Problem is I can't use malloc or free. could memcpy work?

Comment: @GuyBerkovitz You are using `malloc` in your question.

Comment: It was just for the question, I need to use brk or mmap

Comment: @GuyBerkovitz Then this seems like a new question to me. Nothing about that was mentioned in this question.

Comment: Placement-new will work with any memory, including memory from brk() or mmap().